# How to get pagespeed module on nginx running on heroku

Tags: heroku, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, pagespeed

https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed

Thats the module I'd like to use.

I currently have a rails app that is using passenger with nginx. I would like to add the pagespeed module to my app's nginx which is on heroku.

Here are the instructions I followed:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger-ruby-heroku-demo

Answer (score 0):

The basic package managers, yum, apt-get etc install a precompiled nginx which doesn't have pagespeed module enabled.

If you want to use it, you'll need to build nginx from source:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

Since you're asking specifically about Heroku, which I'm not familiar with, it sounds like you're going to need to modify a nginx buildpack to follow the instructions for installing pagespeed above?